# Find the condition on $a, b$ such that the field of $x^3+ax+b\in\Bbb{Q}[x]$ has degree of extension 6.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field

First of all the polynomial $p(x)=x^3+ax+b$ must be irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$, because if not then the degree of extension of its splitting field will be $1$ or $2$.
Now, suppose $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ be three roots of $p(x)$.
Then I observe if we have $[\Bbb{Q}(\alpha):\Bbb{Q}]=3, [\Bbb{Q}(\beta):\Bbb{Q}]=2$ and $\gamma\in\Bbb{Q}(\alpha, \beta)$, then we are done. Because in that case we have $[\Bbb{Q}(\alpha, \beta):\Bbb{Q}]=6$(since $\operatorname{gcd}(3,2)=1$)
But in this manner can I reach the condition on $a$ and $b$?
Can anybody help me in this regard? Thanks for assistance in advance.
**N.B.** I have solved the problem when the degree of extension of its splitting field is $3$.

Comment: If the polynomial is irreducible, the extension generated by $\beta$ has the same degree as the extension generated by $\alpha$. Instead think about the discriminant, or what happens if two of the roots are complex and only one is real.

Comment: if $\sqrt  d $ not in $\Bbb Q$, then $\Bbb Q(\alpha, \beta) $ is splitting field. where $d=-4a^3-27b^2$

Comment: Mustafa, can you prove your claim?

Comment: @BiswarupSaha Since $x^3+ax+b = \prod_{j=1}^3 (x-\alpha_j)$, with the coefficients you know some products and sums of the roots, and there is a special one $d = \prod_{i \ne j} (\alpha_i-\alpha_j)$ whose square root appears when expressing $\alpha_2,\alpha_3$ in term of $\alpha_1,\alpha_1^2$. Also $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3]:\mathbb{Q}]$ always divides $3!$ (the Galois group acts by permuting the roots)